# AZF Custom Handler Breakpoint not Stop

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

A tutorial Custom Handler for AZ Function works but won't stop at breakpoint inside handler. Have Azure Functions Core Tools - 3.0.3904, VSC 1.63.1 (windows 10), Node 14.16

Project structure

```
root
|
|--host.json
|--local.settings
|
|--AF <folder>
|   |-- function.json
|
|--CH <folder>
    |-- app.js
    |-- host.json
```

app.js with Breakpoints:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();    // <--Breakpoint stops when starting
app.get('/cf', (req, res)=>
{
    var t=new Date();     // <--Breakpoint won't stop when hit with browser
    return res.json({users: t + "----" });
});
app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log('CH running', 3333)
})
```

root host.json

```
{
  ...
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
  "customHandler": {
    "description": {
      "defaultExecutablePath": "node",
      "defaultWorkerPath": "CH/app.js"
    },
    "enableForwardingHttpRequest": true
  },
  "extensions": {"http": {"routePrefix": ""}}
}
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node"
  }
}
```

AF/function.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node"
  }
}
```

CH/host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

launch.json

```
{
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "preLaunchTask": "func: host start",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/CH/app.js",
        "request": "launch",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "type": "node"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of CH, we've opted to migrate existing app following this [Re-Factor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/shift-nodejs-express-apis-serverless/)